# Dynamic Array lookup

Tags: microsoft-excel, lookup

[image]

The values in E should match the values in D but don't. Am I using lookup wrong?

This is just a test from a larger problem I'm having. I decided to make a testbed to figure out how to use LOOKUP. My understanding is

`LOOKUP(What you are looking for,where to find it, a name to call it found in the same row`

In the picture I want to find the value 100 in column C which references hypotenuse F found in column D

Comment: Consider using [`VLOOKUP`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0BBC8083-26FE-4963-8AB8-93A18AD188A1) instead of `LOOKUP`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lookup needs the data to be ordered ascending in the lookup array.  Use INDEX MATCH:

```
=INDEX($D$4:$D$13,MATCH(C4,$C$4#,0))
```

[image]

Comment: THANK YOU, also I just learned that you can't filter dynamic arrays, FUN!